# How to increase number of threads processing records in topology?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a Topology :

```
Topology builder = new Topology();
        builder.addSource("source",stringDeserializer,stringDeserializer, "TOPIC-DEV-ACH")
            .addProcessor("process1", ProcessorOne::new , "source")
            .addProcessor("process2", ProcessorTwo::new , "source")
            .addProcessor("process3", ProcessorThree::new , "source")

            .addSink("sink", "asink" ,stringSerializer, stringSerializer, "process1","process2","process3");
```

If I log:
`Thread.currentThread().getName()` in `process(K var1, V var2)`
result :

```
processor1 97527H7-e45cfcd3-6fb7-4fa9-b6a1-b3f5ed122304-StreamThread-1
processor2 97527H7-e45cfcd3-6fb7-4fa9-b6a1-b3f5ed122304-StreamThread-1
processor3 97527H7-e45cfcd3-6fb7-4fa9-b6a1-b3f5ed122304-StreamThread-1
```

I want a multiThreading to execute each Processor in a thread and then merge all results, is it possible with KafkaStreams library?

Comment: If you want a thread for each `Processor` you need to split the topology into multiple sub-topologies that are connected via topics. However, that's not recommended. You should rather scale out horizontally base on input topic partitions. `Topology#describe()` will give you insight into sub-topologies and your current program will have only one sub-topology and sub-topologies can only be scaled horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

A `KafkaStreams` instance uses `StreamThreads` for stream processing.

The number of `StreamThreads` is controlled by `StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG` (`num.stream.threads`) configuration property that defaults to `1` and hence what you see.

Please note that although your Kafka Streams application can use multiple threads, a single topology (with all processors) is executed by a single thread.

A single thread executing a whole topology is simply a Kafka consumer of the source topics and with that it should be obvious that the number of thread (processing a single topology) is exactly the number of partitions of the topics (modulo number of `KafkaStreams` instances of the Kafka Streams application).

Comment: Note, that this will not execute different processors in different thread, but rather allow for horizontal scaling basing on the number of partitions.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax My understanding is that the whole topology (and all processors) are executed in a single thread, but the threads are "Kafka consumers" so we can have as many threads as partitions. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. However, note the sentence of the question: `I want a multiThreading to execute each Processor in a thread and then merge all results, is it possible with KafkaStreams library?` -- hence, your answer is correct (and I upvoted it), but not to the point of the question. -- Compare my comment on the question above.